# How to add a class to parent <li> of selected radio button with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series input fields in a form that I have no access to because it’s dynamically created by a plugin. The code looks like this:

```
<!-- section 1 -->
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="wccf[product][people]" id="wccf_product_people_one" class="wccf wccf_product wccf_radio wccf_product_radio"></input>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="wccf[product][people]" id="wccf_product_people_twp" class="wccf wccf_product wccf_radio wccf_product_radio"></input>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="wccf[product][people]" id="wccf_product_people_three" class="wccf wccf_product wccf_radio wccf_product_radio"></input>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- section 2 -->
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="wccf[product][budget]" id="wccf_product_budget_one" class="wccf wccf_product wccf_radio wccf_product_radio"></input>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="wccf[product][budget]" id="wccf_product_budgete_twp" class="wccf wccf_product wccf_radio wccf_product_radio"></input>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="wccf[product][budget]" id="wccf_product_budget_three" class="wccf wccf_product wccf_radio wccf_product_radio"></input>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add the .checked class to the `<li>` elements that contain a checked radio button.

So far this is the closest I’ve gotten to getting it to work:

```
// Radio buttons for PEOPLE
$('input[name="wccf[product][people]"]').on('click', function() {
    $(".checked").removeClass("checked");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked");
});

// Radio buttons for BUDGET
$('input[name="wccf[product][budget]"]').on('click', function() {
    $(".checked").removeClass("checked");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked");
});
```

The problem is as soon as I select an element on the second section the one that was checked on the first section gets unchecked and viceversa.

Comment: Your problem is in `$(".checked").removeClass("checked");` it points to all elements with the class... you could do `$(this).parent("ul").each(".checked").removeClass("checked");` iterate trough the elements...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" when replacing my code with that. Reading it it makes perfect sense, but I am too new to JS as to be able to figure out why the error is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the selector `$('.checked')`. This selector is not bound to the content of a specific `ul`. Instead, it's traversing the entire DOM for the class, removing it and then setting it on the current parent. Try altering your code like this:

```
$('input[name="wccf[product][people]"], input[name="wccf[product][budget]"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent()
        .siblings('.checked')
        .removeClass('checked')
        .end()
        .addClass('checked');
});
```

You should also note that the `<input />` element is self closing and does not require an end tag <strike>`</input>`</strike>.

Comment: thank you so much for helping out. I've tried your solution but I get "jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name="wccf[product][people], input[name="wccf[product][budget]"]". Unfortunately I'm very new to JS and can't even begin to imagine what that error message could come from...

Comment: As for the '<input>' closing tag, I know, but I have no access to the form in order to remove it, it is generated by a plugin...

Comment: its because he missed off `"]` after `[people]`

Comment: @andrew Thanks. That was a good catch. I've edited the fix into the post.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over all the checkboxes and set the appropriate classes on each change etc

```
var boxes = $('.wccf_product_radio').on('change', function() {
    boxes.filter(':checked')
         .closest('li')
         .addClass('checked')
         .siblings('li')
         .removeClass('checked');
});
```

Comment: Thank you @adeneo. I believe there is a typo in ".wccf wccf_product", shoudnt it be ".wccf.wccf_product". Anyway, this code does add the "checked" class perfectly, but it does not remove it when a different option is selected

Comment: @GuillermoCarone - well, yes, I just copy pasted too fast. A better class would probably be `.wccf_product_radio` as that seems to be for radio buttons, but you have to be the one to figure what classes to target that fits with your markup

Comment: `.wccf.wccf_product` or `.wccf_product_radio` is the only class I need to target, right? Other than that is just the `.checked` class which could be that or anything else. Correct?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but could it be that `boxes.removeClass('checked').filter(':checked')` is looking for an `:checked` element that also has the `.checked` class? If that's the case it wont find it because the `:checked` element is actually inside the `li` with the `.checked` class. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @GuillermoCarone - that's probably it, the order is a little off, and there should be a `siblings` in there